# Como mostrar página customizada para pastas inacessíveis no Windows?

Tags: apache, windows, htaccess, http-status-code-403

Eu usei `ErrorDocument` para configurar as páginas de erro customizadas, mas ao tentar acessar uma pasta que é apenas acessível com privilégios elevados, ao invés de mostrar a página customizada esta exibindo a página padrão de erro do Apache:

<kbd>[image: Página Forbidden]</kbd>

Mas o esperado era algo como:

<kbd>[image: pagina customizada]</kbd>

O que eu tentei foi o seguinte:

- Criei `c:\wamp\www\denyfolderwindows`
- Removi o usuário *Administrator*, removi o usuário *Proprietário* e mantive apenas o usuário *Sistema*.
- Criei um arquivo .htaccess dentro de `c:\wamp\www\` com este conteúdo:

  ```
  ErrorDocument 403 "Oi 403 :)"
  ```
- Acessei a página `http://localhost/denyfolderwindows/`, mas ao invés de mostrar `Oi 403 :)` eu obtive este resultado:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /denyfolderwindows/ on this server.

Note que eu criei uma pasta chamada `c:\wamp\www\denyforapache` e coloquei dentro dela um arquivo .htaccess com este conteúdo:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from All
```

Após navegar para `http://localhost/denyforapache/` me é mostrado isto:

> Oi 403 :)

Ou seja, com `Deny from All` a página customizada funciona, mas com pastas de outros usuários do *Windows* (inacessíveis) não funciona. Não é realmente um problema é apenas curiosidade do porque não funciona.

A estrutura da pasta ficou assim:

```
c:/wamp/www/
├── .htaccess (Contem o errordocument)
├── denyfolderwindows/ (pasta do Windows bloqueada)
└── denyforapache/
    └── .htaccess (bloqueia a pasta usando a diretiva do apache)
```

**Minha duvida:**

Como faço para mostrar páginas *customizadas* ao invés da página *padrão de erro do apache* quando tento navegar para uma pasta *inacessível do Windows*?

### Detalhes

Atualmente o vhosts.conf esta desta maneira:

```
DocumentRoot c:/wamp/www

<Directory c:/wamp/www>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: A resposta para isso é simples. O usuário a qual o Apache está executando não tem permissão de leitura no diretório. É diferente de negar o acesso. Para mostrar uma mensagem de erro é necessário criar uma regra, que pode ser de reescrita de url.

Comment: @MarcosRegis não sei se eu não me fiz entender, isto pra mim esta claro, o que eu quero é que seja exibida a página que eu configurar em `ErrorDocument` ao invés da página padrão de erro do apache.

Comment: O apache no Windows costuma ser executado com o seu usuario. Se esse usuario não possuir as permissões adequadas ele também não possuirá. Lembre-se de que não basta apenas o diretório alvo ter permissão de leitura, seus *pais* também precisam de tal permissão. Isso é verificado antes de que o Apache possa checar que tipo de resposta ele possa dar. Em tempo, esse problema não é de programação o que provavelmente fará com que alguém a sinalize.

Comment: @MarcosRegis O problema se ou possível ou não sendo teórico ou não, induz a uma ferramenta usada em desenvolvimento, o Apache, se o Apache consegue apresentar uma página de erro vinda de `apache2\error\HTTP_FORBIDDEN.html.var` então porque não apresentar uma página customizada? Se o apache trava-se ou emiti-se uma `Warning` então realmente você estaria correto. Mas não é o caso. Sendo assim, se não é algo possivel, então a resposta seria "não é possivel", mas não chega a ser off-topic.

Comment: Entendi seu ponto agora. O Problema é que voce parece ter mudado a resposta no .htaccess mas como o Apache não pode ler o diretório, jamais obterá o texto dele. Para isso voce precisa mudar **ErrorDocument** diretamente no httpd.conf

Comment: Maior recompensa que já vi até hoje :-)

Comment: @Ricardo Também não encontrei nenhuma pergunta que tenha tido tal recompensa :) - mas posso estar enganado

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento você poderia remover o conteúdo da página padrão pelo conteúdo customizado ?

Comment: @Ricardo acredito que não, pois é algo interno do apache, até procurei nos documentos, mas não tenho certeza

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento salvo eu ter entendido errado, é só configurar no apache.conf e por a página de erro numa pasta acessivel por todos, ou mesmo colocar a mensagem personalizada direto no arquivo, se for textual.

Comment: Exemplo, direto no apache.conf: `ErrorDocument 403 "Ei, aqui nao pode."` Precisa ver se o AllowOverride tá permitindo mudar isso no htaccess tambem. O error document pode ser posto em server config, virtual host, directory e .htaccess.

Comment: @Bacco não encontro tal arquivo apache.conf, seria o httpd.conf?

Comment: Pode ser, dependendo do pacote. Se não quiser literal, pode por o caminho, igual faria no htaccess. Só que ponha num lugar onde o apache tenha acesso. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument

Comment: @Bacco parece que é isto mesmo, o teste funcionou aqui, vou testar amanhã tudo certo pra confirmar :) Obrigado!

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento você pode configurar pro 403 mostrar paginas diferentes em pastas diferentes mesmo sem htaccess, basta usar um <directory> para cada caminho. Tem um exemplo no link que eu pus.

Comment: @MarcosRegis Estranhamente recriando todas as pastas desde a www até as pastas internas de www passou a funcionar, não precisei mexer no Apache e em nenhuma configuração, tentei verificar todos usuários da pasta www original, mas parecia idêntico a nova pasta, só posso presumir que o Windows seja um tanto quanto sequelado :p  - Obrigado!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Antes de mais nada

Achei um pouco estranho quando você afirmou isto:

> Criei c:\wamp\www\denyfolderwindows
>   ...
>   Criei um arquivo .htaccess dentro de c:\wamp\www\myfolder ...

Se realmente está desta forma, o `.htaccess` que está em `myfolder` não tem como afetar a pasta `denyfolderwindows`. Cada um dos `.htaccess` de um *host* vale para a pasta onde se encontra, e subpastas dentro desta. Pastas "vizinhas" não são afetadas.

O correto num cenário como o de cima seria por o `.htaccess` ao menos em `c:\wamp\www\`.

Mas supondo que seja apenas um exemplo errado, vamos para outras possibilidades.

### Voltando ao Apache

De acordo com a [documentação do Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument), você pode configurar a diretiva `ErrorDocument` em quatro contextos diferentes.:

- server config
- virtual host
- directory
- .htaccess

Como seu .htaccess pode não estar acessível, você tem as outras 3 opções, sendo o `server config` o contexto principal, que afeta o Apache como um todo. Geralmente apache.conf, ou httpd.conf.

O Virtual Host é o contexto usado quando você serve vários domínios no mesmo IP. Usando o `Error Document` dentro de *virtual hosts* você pode customizar páginas diferentes para cada site.

Se precisar de mais granularidade, com o erro 403 mostrando páginas diferentes em diferentes subdiretórios, e não puder usar `.htaccess`, é o caso de usar o contexto directory:

```
<Directory /minhasubpasta/pastasecreta>
    ErrorDocument 403 /rickrolled.html
</Directory>
<Directory /minhasubpasta/filmes>
    ErrorDocument 403 "403 Access Denied. Olá amiguinho, a senha é SWORDFISH"
</Directory>
```

### A diretiva [AllowOverride](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride)

Independente das permissões, para que o `Error Document` funcione em .htaccess, é necessário que se verifique a diretiva [AllowOverride](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) no httpd.conf.

Ela precisa ter no mínimo a flag `FileInfo` habilitada, senão o `.htaccess` é ignorado como um todo. A opção `All`, como o nome já diz, permite de tudo, mas normalmente não é o desejado numa hospedagem. Por sua vez, `None` é muito restritivo. A [documentação](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) tem uma descrição melhor das opçoes desta diretiva.

### Permissões de arquivo

Fundamental lembrar que o Apache só vai servir as páginas e diretórios que ele mesmo consegue acessar. Isto também vale para arquivos de configuração, incluso `.htaccess`.

Não importam nem um pouco as permissões de arquivo do usuário que está navegando no site, apenas as do Apache.

Em muitas distros Linux o usuário do Apache costuma ser o 48, e ele tem que ter acesso leitura a tudo que for usar.

No Windows é parecido. Uma vez sabendo disto, nas permissões de segurança do Windows você deve permitir que o Apache tenha acesso a todos os arquivos de trabalho. Na dúvida, é bom olhar, por exemplo no Gerenciador de Tarefas (mostrar processos de todos os usuários, se for o caso) e notar quem é o pai da criança.

No Windows, o mais simples é rodar ele como SYSTEM, ou melhor ainda, instalado como *Service*, assim ele já terá os privilégios básicos para fazer o que precisa. Se é uma instalação para uma aplicação em ambiente de produção, você pode criar um usuário separado para o Apache (é até o mais recomendado), mas tem que entender das permissões de arquivo necessárias, para não se complicar.

Neste último caso, ao criar um `.htaccess` novo, lembre-se de que ele pode ter sido criado com as suas credenciais, e não as que o Apache consegue usar. É díficil chegar numa situação dessas no dia-a-dia normal, mas é bom saber que não é impossível.

### Peculiaridades do Explorer do Windows

Para quem está no Windows, tem mais um detalhe interessante: é muito bom que a opção "do mal" de esconder os tipos de extensão para arquivos conhecidos esteja desligada, pois na maioria das vezes ela atrapalha. Por exemplo, um malware "arquivotexto.exe" com um ícone inocente passa por um mero documento.

No caso do `.htaccess` pode acontecer o mesmo. De repente a pessoa acha que criou um `.htaccess`, mas está lá um `.htaccess.txt`. Aliás, se você criar um `.htaccess` diretamente pelo Explorer e ele não reclamar, algo está errado.

O Windows 7 simplesmente não deixa você criar um `.htaccess` direto pelo Explorer, ou renomear um arquivo existente para `.qualquercoisa`, pois ele considera que é um arquivo sem nome. E não adianta querer renomear.

A solução? Tem várias, como criar do zero no seu editor de código e salvar, baixar um via FTP e mudar o conteúdo, ou criar via CMD:

```
echo # > .htaccess
```

### Cuidado com o Internet Explorer

E mais alguns browsers. Muitas vezes acontece do seu erro personalizado estar funcionando, mas não aparecer por que o IE detecta mensagens de erro muito curtas, e troca pelas versões internas dele. A solução para isso é aumentar o número de bytes da página de forma a ficar maior que 512 bytes.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento uma permissão de pasta/arquivo pode impedir o apache de acessar o .htaccess, depende da conta de usuário que o Apache está usando (e não de quem acessa). Pra evitar problemas, o ideal é o apache rodar como service na conta SYSTEM, por exemplo. Depois vou ver se trabalho isso na resposta, parei à noite pq tava meio cansado. Mas independente da pergunta, se precisar de ajuda pra configurar num caso real, vamos trocando comentários, na medida do possível, até resolver.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento mas vc conferiu as permissões do windows? Quem é o usuário dono do arquivo, e quem pode ler? Pra testar melhor, copie esse htaccess e renomeie a copia pra teste.txt, e veja se consegue ver ele pelo browser

Comment: normalmente o apache nao precisaria estar elevado, bastaria ler os arquivos. Não como solução definitiva, mas acrescente "everyone" com permissão de leitura no .htaccess e veja se muda algo (e aquele teste de ver se como .txt ele aparece no browser é legal tambem). Como tá o seu allowoverride do httpd.conf atualmente?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32583/discussion-between-guilherme-nascimento-and-bacco).

Comment: Deletei a outra resposta, parece que encontrei o problema :/ uma coisa muito estranha rs. Obrigado por tudo!!

Comment: ainda sim mesmo que fosse uma questão do Windows, o arquivo .htaccess dentro da pasta `denyfolderwindows` não continha nada, era um arquivo vazio. Provavelmente o Apache alcança o .htaccess, mas não consegue ler ele então emite o Forbidden para o `denyfolderwindows/.htaccess` e não para o `denyfolderwindows`, não sei se ficou claro, mas creio que realmente é um pequeno bug do apache.

Answer (score 3):

Esta é uma resposta complementar, apenas para entender o porque do `ErrorDocument` não funcionar como o esperado.

Após uma longa analise sobre os diretórios antigos, eu percebi que dentro da pasta `denyfolderwindows` existia um arquivo *.htaccess* também.

A estrutura estava assim:

```
c:/wamp/www/
├── .htaccess (Contem o errordocument)
└── denyfolderwindows/ (pasta do Windows bloqueada)
    └── .htaccess (este arquivo é vazio)
└── denyforapache/
    └── .htaccess (bloqueia a pasta usando a diretiva do apache)
```

- Se acessar `http://localhost/denyfolderwindows/` e existir o tal arquivo `c:/wamp/denyfolderwindows/.htaccess` (mesmo que este arquivo esteja vazio) a página customizada não é exibida.
- Se renomear o arquivo *.htaccess* para `.foo`, ficando assim:

  ```
  c:/wamp/www/
  ├── .htaccess (Contem o errordocument)
  └── denyfolderwindows/ (pasta do Windows bloqueada)
      └── .foo (este arquivo é vazio)
  └── denyforapache/
      └── .htaccess (bloqueia a pasta usando a diretiva do apache)
  ```

  E remover as permissões de `denyfolderwindows` em seguida tentar acessar a página `http://localhost/denyfolderwindows/` é mostrado a página customizada esperada, que no meu caso exibe o seguinte conteudo:

  > Oi 403 :)

### Conclusão

Isto é aparentemente um conflito do Apache, pois ele de alguma maneira consegue notar o arquivo `.htaccess`, mesmo a pasta estando sem usuário algum:

<kbd>[image: Permissões de pasta do Windows]</kbd>

Pode ser até mesmo uma questão do NTFS (eu não posso afirmar isto), mas ainda sim parece ser um conflito do Apache quando existe o arquivo .htaccess dentro de uma pasta sem permissão, mesmo sendo estranho o Apache conseguir saber que existe um arquivo dentro da pasta que não tem privilégios para nenhum usuário.

> Nota eu tentei renomear o arquivo para `c:/wamp/denyfolderwindows/.htaccesss` (com 3 letras "s") e o `ErrorDocument` do `c:/wamp/.htaccess` funcionou exibindo a página customizada, em outras palavras o problema só ocorre se existir um arquivo assim `c:/wamp/denyfolderwindows/.htaccess` e acaba por exibir a página de erro (Forbidden) padrão do Apache.

Esta situação de criar uma pasta inacessível dentro da pasta publica é improvável de ocorrer em um servidor de produção, isso tudo foi apenas um caso de estudo para entender como o `.htaccess` se comporta em diferentes situações.

Comment: você também pode tentar adicionar um url externo para o ErrorDocument, algo como: "<html><head><title>NO!</title></head><body><h2><tt>Oi 403 :)</tt></h2></body></html> um detalhe que observei foi o uso da Aspas dupla no inicio e não precisa delas no final, não sei se influenciaria em algo no seu caso, pode também passar uma pagina própria para ser carregada ErrorDocument 403 /erros/403.php, ainda pode definir usuários no htaccess veja aqui: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/auth.html

Comment: @JúniorMoreira Obrigado, o `ErrorDocument 403 "Oi 403 :)"` foi um exemplo bem basico, tipo um `Hello World`, o meu arquivo original é sim um path valido `ErrorDocument 403 /www/403.html`. Mas legal a dica da aspa ser necessária apenas no começo.